# iPhone Multi touch interactive to CorePlot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-plot

I'm developing an iPhone application with core-plot chart. With the help of some tutorials, i managed to do it with single touch and drag. How can I make it with multiple touch and drag? Anybody please help me?

[image]

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    EskPlotTheme *defaultTheme = [[EskPlotTheme alloc] init];
    linePlot = [[EskLinePlot alloc] init];
    linePlot.delegate = self;
    [linePlot renderInLayer:lineHostingView withTheme:defaultTheme]; 
    [defaultTheme release];    
}
```

**EskLinePlot.m**

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
    {
        // setting up the sample data here.
        sampleData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:6000],
                                                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:3000],
                                                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:2000],
                                                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:5000],
                                                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:7000],
                                                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:8500],
                                                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:6500], nil];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)renderInLayer:(CPTGraphHostingView *)layerHostingView withTheme:(CPTTheme *)theme
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    CGRect bounds = layerHostingView.bounds;

    // Create the graph and assign the hosting view.
    graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
    layerHostingView.hostedGraph = graph;
    [graph applyTheme:theme];

    graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;

    // chang the chart layer orders so the axis line is on top of the bar in the chart.
    NSArray *chartLayers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypePlots],
                                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeMajorGridLines], 
                                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeMinorGridLines],  
                                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeAxisLines], 
                                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeAxisLabels], 
                                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeAxisTitles], 
                                                            nil];
    graph.topDownLayerOrder = chartLayers;    
    [chartLayers release];

    // Add plot space for horizontal charts
    graph.paddingLeft = 60.0;
    graph.paddingTop = 70.0;
    graph.paddingRight = 20.0;
    graph.paddingBottom = 20.0;

    // Setup plot space
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
    plotSpace.delegate = self;
    int sampleCount = [sampleData count]-1;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(sampleCount)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(10000)];

    // Setup grid line style
    CPTMutableLineStyle *majorXGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    majorXGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    majorXGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.25f];

    CPTMutableTextStyle *whiteTextStyle = [[[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init] autorelease];
    whiteTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];    

    // Setup x-Axis.
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
    CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.majorGridLineStyle = majorXGridLineStyle;
    x.labelTextStyle = whiteTextStyle;
    x.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromString(@"1");
    x.minorTicksPerInterval = 1;

    NSArray *exclusionRanges = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(0)], nil];
    x.labelExclusionRanges = exclusionRanges;

    // Setup y-Axis.
    CPTMutableLineStyle *majorYGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    majorYGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    majorYGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.25];

    CPTMutableLineStyle *minorYGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    minorYGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    minorYGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1];

    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.majorGridLineStyle = majorYGridLineStyle;
    y.minorGridLineStyle = minorYGridLineStyle;
    y.labelTextStyle = whiteTextStyle;
    y.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromString(@"1000");
    y.minorTicksPerInterval = 1;
    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
    NSArray *yExlusionRanges = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0)],
                                nil];
    y.labelExclusionRanges = yExlusionRanges;

    // Create a high plot area
    CPTScatterPlot *highPlot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
    highPlot.identifier = kHighPlot;

    CPTMutableLineStyle *highLineStyle = [[highPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy] autorelease];
    highLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.f;
    highLineStyle.miterLimit        = 1.0f;
    highLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    highPlot.dataLineStyle = highLineStyle;
    highPlot.dataSource = self;

    CPTColor *areaColor1       = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.8f];
    CPTGradient *areaGradient1 = [CPTGradient gradientWithBeginningColor:areaColor1 endingColor:[[CPTColor whiteColor]  colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2f]];
    areaGradient1.angle = -90.0f;
    CPTFill *areaGradientFill = [CPTFill fillWithGradient:areaGradient1];
    highPlot.areaFill       = areaGradientFill;
    highPlot.areaBaseValue = [[NSDecimalNumber zero] decimalValue];
    [graph addPlot:highPlot];

    // Create the Savings Marker Plot
    selectedCoordination = 2;

    touchPlot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull] autorelease];
    touchPlot.identifier = kLinePlot;
    touchPlot.dataSource = self;
    touchPlot.delegate = self;
    [self hideTouchPlotColor];
    [graph addPlot:touchPlot];

    [pool drain];

}

- (void)hideTouchPlotColor
{
    CPTColor *touchPlotColor = [CPTColor clearColor];

    CPTMutableLineStyle *savingsPlotLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    savingsPlotLineStyle.lineColor = touchPlotColor;

    CPTPlotSymbol *touchPlotSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    touchPlotSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:touchPlotColor];
    touchPlotSymbol.lineStyle = savingsPlotLineStyle;
    touchPlotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(12.0f, 12.0f);

    CPTMutableLineStyle *touchLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    touchLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor clearColor];
    touchLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;

    CPTMutableLineStyle *symbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    symbolLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor clearColor];
    CPTPlotSymbol *plotSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    plotSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor clearColor]];
    plotSymbol.lineStyle = symbolLineStyle;
    plotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0);
    touchPlot.plotSymbol = plotSymbol;

    touchPlot.dataLineStyle = touchLineStyle;
}

// Assign different color to the touchable line symbol.
- (void)showTouchPlotColor
{
    CPTColor *touchPlotColor = [CPTColor orangeColor];

    CPTMutableLineStyle *savingsPlotLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    savingsPlotLineStyle.lineColor = touchPlotColor;

    CPTPlotSymbol *touchPlotSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    touchPlotSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:touchPlotColor];
    touchPlotSymbol.lineStyle = savingsPlotLineStyle;
    touchPlotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(12.0f, 12.0f); 

    CPTMutableLineStyle *touchLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    touchLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor orangeColor];
    touchLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;

    CPTMutableLineStyle *symbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    symbolLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
    CPTPlotSymbol *plotSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    plotSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor orangeColor]];
    plotSymbol.lineStyle = symbolLineStyle;
    plotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0);
    touchPlot.plotSymbol = plotSymbol;

    touchPlot.dataLineStyle = touchLineStyle;
}

// This method is call when user touch & drag on the plot space.
- (BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDraggedEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    // Convert the touch point to plot area frame location
    CGPoint pointInPlotArea = [graph convertPoint:point toLayer:graph.plotAreaFrame];

    NSDecimal newPoint[2];
    [graph.defaultPlotSpace plotPoint:newPoint forPlotAreaViewPoint:pointInPlotArea];
    NSDecimalRound(&newPoint[0], &newPoint[0], 0, NSRoundPlain);
    int x = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:newPoint[0]] intValue];

    if (x < 0)
    {
        x = 0;
    }
    else if (x > [sampleData count])
    {
        x = [sampleData count];
    }

        selectedCoordination = x;
        if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(linePlot:indexLocation:)])
            [delegate linePlot:self indexLocation:x];
        [touchPlot reloadData];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDownEvent:(id)event 
          atPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    [self showTouchPlotColor];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceUpEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    [self hideTouchPlotColor];
    touchPlotSelected = NO;
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - 
#pragma mark Scatter plot delegate methods

- (void)scatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if ([(NSString *)plot.identifier isEqualToString:kLinePlot]) 
    {
        touchPlotSelected = YES;
        [self applyHighLightPlotColor:plot];
        if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(linePlot:indexLocation:)])
            [delegate linePlot:self indexLocation:index];
    } 
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Plot Data Source Methods

- (NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot 
{
    if ([(NSString *)plot.identifier isEqualToString:kLinePlot]) 
    {
        return kNumberOfMarkerPlotSymbols;
    }
    else {
        return [sampleData count];
    }
}

- (NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index 
{
    NSNumber *num = nil;
    if ( [(NSString *)plot.identifier isEqualToString:kHighPlot] )
    {
        if ( fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldY ) 
        {
            num = [sampleData objectAtIndex:index];
        } 
        else if (fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX) 
        {
            num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:index];
        }
    }
    else if ([(NSString *)plot.identifier isEqualToString:kLinePlot]) 
    {
        if ( fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldY ) 
        {
            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1000];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:12700];
                    break;
                default:
                    num = [sampleData objectAtIndex:selectedCoordination];
                    break;
            }
        } 
        else if (fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX) 
        {
            num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:selectedCoordination];
        }
    }

    return num;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using touchesBegan:withEvent: method? You can read all touches by >
NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];

switch ([allTouches count]) {
case 1: { //Single touch
etc..

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same problem recently and couldn't find any solution. After some time researching and coding I found some solutions and want to share one, quite easy one, so it may help you get an idea how to approach this.

I have created transparent UIView, which I've put on top of CPTGraphHostingView. 
This view was handling needed touch events.
Let's name it TestView

TestView.h file looks like

```
@protocol TestViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)myTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)myTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)myTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

@end

@interface TestView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <TestViewDelegate>delegate;
@end
```

TestView.m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self.delegate myTouchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self.delegate myTouchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self.delegate myTouchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

TestView delegate, in my case viewController, which includes corePlot hosting view,  will implement those methods and see the sample of the code below

```
- (void)myTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if (touches.count == 1) {
        UITouch *touch = (UITouch *)[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
        CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:nil];
        [self plotSpace:self.plotSpace shouldHandlePointingDeviceDraggedEvent:event atPoint:point];
    }
    if (touches.count == 2) {
        UITouch *touch = (UITouch *)[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:1];
        CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:nil];
        [self plotSpace:self.plotSpace shouldHandlePointingDeviceDraggedEvent:event atPoint:point];
    }
}
```

CPTPlotSpace delegate method in viewController will look like

```
- (BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDraggedEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point{
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    if ([allTouches count] >0 ) {
        UITouch *touch1 = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
        if (touch1){
            CGPoint pointInPlotArea = [self.graph convertPoint:[touch1 locationInView:self.view] toLayer:self.graph.plotAreaFrame];
//              padding
            pointInPlotArea.x -=10;
            NSDecimal newPoint[2];
            [self.graph.defaultPlotSpace plotPoint:newPoint forPlotAreaViewPoint:pointInPlotArea];
            NSDecimalRound(&newPoint[0], &newPoint[0], 0, NSRoundPlain);
            int x = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:newPoint[0]] intValue];
            x--;

            if (x <= 0)
                x = 0;
            else if (x >= [self.currentDatapoints count])
                x = [self.currentDatapoints count] - 1;

            selectedCoordination = x;
            self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.currentDatapoints objectAtIndex:x]];
            self.differenceLabel.text = @"";
            [touchPlot reloadData];
        }
        if ([allTouches count] > 1){
            secondTouchPlot.hidden = NO;
            UITouch *touch2 = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:1];
            if (touch2) {
                CGPoint pointInPlotArea = [self.graph convertPoint:[touch2 locationInView:self.view] toLayer:self.graph.plotAreaFrame];
                pointInPlotArea.x -= 10;
                NSDecimal newPoint[2];
                [self.graph.defaultPlotSpace plotPoint:newPoint forPlotAreaViewPoint:pointInPlotArea];
                NSDecimalRound(&newPoint[0], &newPoint[0], 0, NSRoundPlain);
                int x = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:newPoint[0]] intValue];
                x--;
                if (x <= 0)
                    x = 0;
                else if (x >= [self.currentDatapoints count])
                    x = [self.currentDatapoints count] - 1;

                selectedCoordination2 = x;
                self.secondLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.currentDatapoints objectAtIndex:x]];
                [secondTouchPlot reloadData];
                float first = [self.label.text floatValue];
                float second = [[self.currentDatapoints objectAtIndex:x] floatValue];
                self.differenceLabel.textColor = (first - second) > 0 ? [UIColor greenColor] : [UIColor redColor];
                self.differenceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", first - second];

            }
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

And that's the result...

[image]

This is not optimized code, it's just the idea, as I mentioned above, how to approach this problem.

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 2):

I will most likely end up answering this question in multiple responses, but I will at this point begin with:

You would think Apple would have provided APIs to aid with multiple finger tracking algorithms, etc... within their Gesture Recognition objects, but they have not thus far.  In the game that I developed, I needed to also have multiple fingers, up to 4 and beyond, all on screen and moving / tracking all at once.  What I found was I had to implement my own finger tracking / down / up algorithms to accomplish things other than simple single finger swipes, and pinch-to-zoom operations. Lets dig in:

I beleive in your EskLinePlot.m file "should handle down events", you are going to need to implement an incrementer of "how many fingers are down".  This way if you get another finger down when another is already down you will have a count of it.  Similarly you are going to need to implement a decrementer in the "should handle up events" routine.  In the middle of all this, will also need to be an (albeit) small database (probably an NSMutableArray) of touches.  This database will be used to correlate the drag events to a finger.  So how ultimately with this work.  On a down event, you will:
     1) create a new record in the touch database (the array number can act as your unique identifier
     2) Record the new touch's current position into the (new) touch record you created in step 1 as the newest (or array position 0) position.  Each touch item in the touch database should have a history of somewhere between 4 and 10 of the last positions the finger has been at (I tend to record positions as 0 = newest to 3 or 9 as the oldest).
     3) Instead of simply turning on the SINGLE (graphical) line you have created, add a new (graphical) line when the down event has occured (doing the same correlation you are currently doing for screen finger position to graph numeric position)

For the "should process drag events":
     1) Look at the sceen position of the finger being relayed in the drag event and correlate it to a touch within your internally held touch database (which touch in your touch database is closest to the one being presented at this time).
     2) shift all previous position points for the correlated touch down by 1.  0 goes to 1, 1 goes to 2, etc... through all and of course drop the last one.
     3) add the new point to the correalated touch's list of previous points as the newest point.
     4) Move the (graphical) line that was correlated to that finger appropriately

For an up event:
     1) correlate the position presented to a finger within your touch database.
     2) remove the correlated touch from your touch database.
     3) remove the (graphical) line that you had assigned to that finger from the screen

I hope this helps, I should be able to find some sample code somewhere, but I am not currently in front of my development machine.