# Core Plot Multiple Selection

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

i'm creating a stock chart, where i need to be able to select a period range from a chart and display that period on other chart. To do that i need to be able to have 2 select points on first chart to select values.

I saw this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632421/iphone-multi-touch-interactive-to-coreplot), but it doesn't have enough explanation on how to do it, since i'm a newbie regarding to Core Plot and chart manipulation.

Can someone provide some sample code about this question?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135829/

Comment: My problem is not getting index of points, but create the Line of selection... So, i can get index of points, i just can create both lines on same graphic.

Answer (score 0):

Use scatter plots to draw the selection lines. You can draw them both with the same plot if you want the same line style. The Mac version of the *CPTTestApp* example app includes a selection demo that uses a scatter plot to draw a cross shape over the selected point. You could easily modify that to draw only the vertical line.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using [HighStocks Charts](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock)and embedded it on a webview and load HTML pages with JS.

Thank You all for your help.